# Group Sum On Join Query Where One Side Is Empty

Tags: c#, linq, join, null, sum

I have an order class and shipment class.

```cs
class Order 
{
   public long ID;
   public decimal ApprovedQuantity {get; set;}
}

class Shipment  
{
   public long OrderID {get; set;}
   public decimal SentAmount {get; set;}
}
```

Order and Shipment have a One to Many relationship in which one Order may be split into many Shipment records. I need to write a query for non sent amount of Order class.

So far this is what I've come with but unfortunately, when there is no shipment record on the database it throws an error saying can not assign null value to decimal.

```
var items = from o in orders
               join shp in shipments on o.ID equals shp.OrderID into groupedShp
               let sentAmount = groupedShp.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(shp => shp.SentAmount)
               select new
               {
                  o.ID,                               
                  NotSentAmount = o.ApprovedQuantity - Convert.ToDecimal(sentAmount)
               };
```

The Error:
`The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.`

**Edit**:

I changed the `.Sum` method to this and it worked.

```
let sentAmount = groupedShp.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(shp => (decimal?)shp.SentAmount) ?? 0
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage Linq2Sql, MsSQL

Comment: Try `let sentAmount = groupedShp.Any() ? groupedShp.Sum(shp => shp.SentAmount) : 0`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code for the following:

```
var items = from o in orders
           join shp in shipments on o.ID equals shp.OrderID into groupedShp
           let sentAmount = groupedShp.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(shp => shp == null ? 0 : shp.SentAmount ?? 0)
           select new
           {
              o.ID,                               
              NotSentAmount = o.ApprovedQuantity - Convert.ToDecimal(sentAmount)
           };
```

`DefaultIfEmpty()` in case when the shipments table is empty will return a `null` object that does not have the `SentAmount` property, therefore causing the exception.

Comment: Compiler says "CS8072 An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator."

Comment: I edited the answer to be compatible with `IQueryable<T>` implementations.